# Getting SQLite3 to work with multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlite, multiprocessing

I'm making a web crawler in Python that collects redirects/links, adds them to a database, and enters them as a new row if the link doesn't already exist. I want like to use multi-threading but having trouble because I have to check in real time if there is an entry with a given URL.

I was initially using `sqlite3` but realised I can't use it simultaneously on different threads. I don't really want to use MySQL (or something similar) as it needs more disk space and runs as separate server. Is there anyway to make `sqlite3` work with multiple threads?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Python `sqlite3` module has a [`threadsafety`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#threadsafety) level of 1, which means that although you can't share database *connections* between threads, multiple threads can use the *module* simultaneously.  So, you *could* have each thread create its own connection to the database.

The problem with this approach is that SQLite has poor write concurrency, so having multiple threads doing a ton of `INSERT`s at once will give you the dreaded “database is locked” error.  You can improve things somewhat by using [`PRAGMA JOURNAL_MODE = 'WAL'`](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html), but that only goes so far.

If performance is an issue and switching to a client-server database isn't an option, then what you'll probably have to do is keep an in-memory cache of your URLs, and arrange your program so that you have *one* thread that syncs this cache with the SQLite database.

Comment: but what about mysql? does it have this safety feature?

Comment: I would just recommend what @dan04 wrote and create a class to handle that connection. That way, all threads could instantiate the class as needed which could automatically set up the database and connection.

Comment: You also may increase `timeout` value of connection, which will make it wait longer for database to become unlocked. This will slow down concurrent writes, but they will eventually all complete.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to acquire a lock to access the database directly from your program. In this way the multiple threads or processes will wait the other processes to insert the link before performing a request.

Comment: Unfortunately "you cannot have your cake and eat it too". Either you want a proper database, or avoid running a database, I'm afraid. I'm also not sure about what do you want to achieve. How can you be sure by the time you make a SELECT request, check if the url is there, and eventually do something else before INSERTing, some other process wouldn't sneak in a INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to make sqlite work in multiple threads.

Use BlockingCollection with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem.
Any database query are queued and executed in FIFO (First In First Out) order.
Now the database is never locked while doing any SQL transaction from any thread.
This is an example in C#.

```
public class DatabaseQueueBus
{
    private BlockingCollection<TransportBean> _dbQueueBus = new BlockingCollection<TransportBean>(new ConcurrentQueue<TransportBean>());
    private CancellationTokenSource __dbQueueBusCancelToken;

    public CancellationTokenSource _dbQueueBusCancelToken { get => __dbQueueBusCancelToken; set => __dbQueueBusCancelToken = value; }

    public DatabaseQueueBus()
    {
        _dbQueueBusCancelToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
        DatabaseQueue();

    }

    public void AddJob(TransportBean dto)
    {
        _dbQueueBus.Add(dto);
    }

    private void DatabaseQueue()
    {

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((param) =>
        {
            try
            {
                do
                {
                    string job = "";
                    TransportBean dto = _dbQueueBus.Take(_dbQueueBusCancelToken.Token);
                    try
                    {
                        job = (string)dto.DictionaryTransBean["job"];
                        switch (job)
                        {
                            case "SaveClasse":
                                //Save to table here
                                break;
                            case "SaveRegistrant":
                                //Save Registrant here
                                break;
                          
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {//TODO: Handle this exception or not

                    }

                } while (_dbQueueBusCancelToken.Token.IsCancellationRequested != true);
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```